# need an explanation about object destructing in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

How does this code work?

Isn't this an object assigned to the fullname? `fullName: {firstName: name}`

then how is the `name` variable works?

```js
const user = {
  id: 42,
  displayName: 'jdoe',
  fullName: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  }
};

function whois({displayName, fullName: {firstName: name}}) {
  return `${displayName} is ${name}`;
}

console.log(
  whois(user)
)
```

Comment: It is just renaming the firstName - this would work too but means a longer template literal: `function whois({displayName, fullName}) {  return \`${displayName} is ${fullName.firstName}\`;}`

Comment: the example is from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) and is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't this an object assigned to the `fullname`? `fullName: {firstName: name}`

If you mean in the `const user = ...` statement, yes.

> then how is the `name` variable works?

The parameter list for `whois` uses this destructuring pattern:

```
{displayName, fullName: {firstName: name}}
```

Let's use `x` to refer to the argument the function receives (since it doesn't have any name in the function).

- The `displayName` part of that stores `x.displayName` in a (destructured) parameter called `displayName` (the same as the property name).
- The `fullName: { firstName: name }` part of that stores `x.fullName.firstName` in a (destructured) parameter called `name`.

Object destructuring syntax is **exactly** the same as object literal syntax, it just goes the other direction (and requires that the target of the value be something that can be assigned to). In an object literal, `a: b` means "create an `a` property getting the value from `b`." In destructuring, it means "assign the value of the `a` property to `b`".

Here's a simpler example. Consider this object literal:

```
const theNameIs = "Joe";
const example = {
    name: theNameIs,
//    ^       V
//    |       |
//    +−<−<−<−+
};
```

The `name` property in the object receives its value from the `theNameIs` variable.

Now consider this destructuring pattern:

```
let {name: theNameIs} = example;
//    V       ^
//    |       |
//    +−>−>−>−+
```

That works the same way, just in the other direction: The `theNameIs` variable receives its value from the `name` property on `example`.

Comment: FWIW, I go into destructuring in detail in Chapter 7 of my recent book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev).

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring works as follows:

1. You receive an object;
2. You only need some specific keys;
3. You want to rename certain keys;

Examples:

```js
const user = { firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'bar', age: 99 };

const firstname = ({ firstname }) => firstname;
const lastname = ({ lastname }) => lastname;
const names = ({ firstname, lastname }) => ({ firstname, lastname });

const renameAge = ({ age: renamedAge, ...props }) => ({
  ...props,
  renamedAge
})

console.log(firstname(user)) // foo
console.log(lastname(user)) // bar
console.log(names(user)) // { firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'bar' }
console.log(renameAge(user)) // { firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'bar', renameAge: 99}
```

So to make it clear:

```
function whois({displayName, fullName: {firstName: name}}) {
  return `${displayName} is ${name}`;
}
```

Accepts 2 arguments where fullName is an object with `firstName` as a key. But to make it pretty or to prevent collision with existing variable names, `firstName` is converted to `name`. Another real world example:

```
function whois({displayName, fullName: {firstName: name}}) {
  const firstName = 'foo';
  return `${displayName} is ${firstName} ${name}`;
}
```